# GA4: Track revenue by custom events

Tags: google-tag-manager, google-analytics-4

I have ecommerce data setup (and revenue) for Purchase event/conversion, and we need to show revenue for the following conversions/events:

- Purchase by a new customer
- Purchase by an old customer

Is there any way to use GTM to filter revenue by custom conversions?

Or we need to send revenue to new events again?

I created custom events, but revenue is 0 for them.

Comment: Add a user property can do the filter. So how to tell the user is new or old is the key. There are some information that teaching how to build audience could also be a solution.

Comment: Agree with @darrelltw, you need to define what a new/old user is. You can leverage the data already within GA4 but there are deficiencies in that (a new user could be an old user but on a new device, new user could be an old user who cleared cookies). You probably don't need a new event, just pass some additional parameters with the event but those data points won't be historical, obviously.